# Why a reference to object is replaced with its value

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, reference, express

I use node.js and express.

I saved on the '`req.session`' a complex object that includes array of objects.
In addition I save reference to one of the objects in the array.
For example:

```
var value = {
    name: "name"
    , values: []
};

req.session.value = value;

//
// I populate 'req.session.value' with values (with the same structure)
//

// then I save reference to one of the inner objects

var currentValue = req.session.value[3];

//
// later I try to change the save object
//

currentValue.name = "newName";
```

I expected that if I change the '`currentValue`' then the '`req.session.value[3]`' will be changed as well. However, for some reason it doesn't happen.

To be concrete, if I change the `currentValue` immediately after I assign it then the `req.session.value[3]` is changed but if I am doing it in the next call then just the `currentValue` is changed.

In the example: I do the assignments to the '`req.session`' in the "`app.get(...)`" if I change the value of the `currentValue` in the "`app.get(...)`" it is run ok (the value change in both places) but if I change it in the  '`app.post(...)`' the only object that change is the `currentValue` while the `req.session.value[3]` left the same.

Thanks in advance,
Shai

The code:

```
'app.get("/template/:templateid/feature/add", isTemplate, function(req, res) {'
'    if (!req.session.features) { // if features empty'
''
'    // Save the first features level from the current template in the session '
'    req.session.features = req.session.template.feature;'
'    //'
'    if (!req.session.featureNodes) { // featureNotes is a stack/branch of the features'
'        req.session.featureNodes = [];'
'    }'
'    if (!req.query.featureroot || req.query.featureroot == "") {'
'    } else {'
'        var featureRoot = getFeature(req.query.featureroot, req.session.features); // get one object from req.session.features'
'        if (featureRoot) {'
'            req.session.featureNodes.push(featureRoot);     // save reference'
'            var featureR = req.session.featureNodes.pop();  // do check that work!'
'            var values = {'
'                name: "req.body.name"'
'                , description: "req.body.description"'
'                , wieght: "req.body.wieght"'
'                , created: new Date()'
'                , modified: new Date()'
'                , feature: []'
'            };'
''
'            featureR.feature.push(values); // also req.session.features changed'
'            req.session.featureNodes.push(featureRoot); // push the reference back for use later'
'        }      '
'    }'
'    res.render("addfeature2template.jade", { '
'        title: "Add new feature"'
'        ,template: req.session.template'
'        ,feature: req.session.featureNodes'
'    });'
'});'
''
'app.post("/feature/add", isUser, function(req, res) {'
'    var SUBMIT = "Create";'
'    var CANCEL = "Cancel";'
'    switch ( req.param("feature") ) {'
'        case SUBMIT:'
'            var fields = {  name: 1, description: 1, wieght: 1};'
'            var values = {'
'                name: req.body.name'
'                , description: req.body.description'
'                , wieght: req.body.wieght'
'                , created: new Date()'
'                , modified: new Date()'
'                , feature: []'
'            };'
'            if (req.session.featureNodes.length < 1) {'
'                req.session.features.push(values);'
'            } else {'
'                var featureRoot = req.session.featureNodes.pop(); // pop the reference'
'                featureRoot.feature.push(values);                 // change the object but the req.session.features didnt changed '
'            }'
'            req.session.template = template;'
'            res.redirect("/template/" + req.body.templateid);'
'        break;'
'        case CANCEL:'
'            res.redirect("/template/" + req.body.templateid);'
'            break;'
'    }'
'});'
```

Comment: If `req.session.value[3]` starts off as a string, then under no circumstances *ever* will changing `currentValue` again *after* the assigment have any effect on `req.session.value[3]`.  That's just not the way JavaScript works; if you think you're seeing that happen, then you're misinterpreting something (hard to say what from what you've posted).

Comment: oops, I wrote: "var currentValue = req.session.value[3];" but I ment  "var currentValue = req.session.value.values[3];" - is it reasonable now?

Comment: Well assignment statements in JavaScript always just make copies of values. You cannot make one variable an alias for another variable, or object property (which is what array elements are).

Comment: Isn't object assignment is just the reference assignment? Whenever I change the currentValue content immediately after I set it to the value "req.session.value[3]" then any change that I made in currentValue  also reflected in req.session.value[3]. The same changes were not reflected to "req.session.value[3]" whenever I did it in the "app.post(...)" - do you have any idea why it is happen?

Comment: If you're changing the *contents* of the object referenced, then that's different :-)  Without seeing more of the actual code where there's an apparent difference, it's hard to say.  Exactly what does your "POST" code look like?

Comment: How can I load the code?

Comment: Edit your question by clicking the "edit" link, and add the "post" code.

Comment: Thanks - I added the code. I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.session` object is serialized (to store) between the requests.

Example:

Request 1:

```
req.session = {};
var a = { hello : 'world' };
var b = a;
req.session.a = a;
req.session.b = b;
```

In this context variables `a`, `b`, `req.session.a`, `req.session.b` points to one object. You can change field `hello` in any of these objects, and this will to change in each of them.

After end of request `req.session` object will be serialized for session storage (memcached, mongodb, etc).

Request 2:

Before request 2 `req.session` object will be deserialized from storage. Now it contains plain values without references. You can access `req.session.a` and `req.session.b` but now it two different objects.